# Ctrl + space giving error saying 'Computing additional info' has encountered a problem

Tags: eclipse, scala-ide

So I am using Eclipse and I have installed Scala IDE. There when I press `Ctrl + space`, I get an error pop up saying `'Computing additional info' has encountered a problem`. I tried using solutions given in many SO threads regarding of shortcut not working but in vein. I tried content assist tricks but no luck.

Below is the snapshot I took. I am using Windows 10 and eclipse latest version
2018-09(4.9.0).

[image: Error Snapshot]